# Rollback driver in Windows via command line

Tags: windows, command-line, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a remote system in which I've updated the Nvidia graphics driver, but now RDPDD.dll, which I'm guessing stands for RDP Display Driver, will not load (found this out via Event Viewer).  I can use Sysinternal's Psexec to execute commands though.

I'm sure something has gone very wrong and the user of this system (a CAD engineer) won't be able to use his system normally.  I've tried two remote reboots and that has not resolved the issue.

So I would like to use the "Roll Back" option for the Nvidia driver in the device manager.  Is there a command-line way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [DevCon application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) to perform driver update operations from the command line.

Comment: Great idea.  Did some googling and some stuff here seems interesting... http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=327343

Comment: But how do you Roll Back a driver using devcon? Specifically?

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar situation where I needed to use the generic MS driver since the native one has issues and I couldn't wait for a proper fix from vendor.

The (indirect) way I found to rollback drivers using devcon:

```
Devcon.exe updateNI <INF file> <HW ID>
```

`updateNI`: Specifies non-interactive update. according to needs `update` can be used instead.

`INF file`: The driver you want to forcibly install even though the previous one is more recent.

`HW ID`: Hardware ID of the device

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544835(v=vs.85).aspx