# Is there a way of scripting the "Roll Back Driver" feature of Window's Device Manager?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, graphics, device-manager

I need to roll back my graphic cards drivers once in a while(It's a long story.) and I have tried scripts using devmanview which worked great for disabling and enabling my drivers(and uninstalling it) but I need the "Roll Back Driver" feature.

Is there a way to script the "Roll Back Driver" features for the Device Manager?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rollback driver in Windows via command line](http://superuser.com/questions/200373/rollback-driver-in-windows-via-command-line)

Comment: @DavidPostill They never posted how to roll back a driver specifically.